# troubleshooting slow SSH login

Tags: ssh

How can I go about troubleshooting a problem like this?

```
1. login as: 
2. Keyboard-interactive authentication prompts from server:
3. | Password:
4. End of keyboard-interactive prompts from server
5. Last login: Mon Dec  2 13:24:07 2019 from elsewhere
6. prompt>
```

1. open putty window, immediately connects to system and `login as:` is present.  It's a 1gbps wired network, and transferring data to/from system via samba runs at 110 MB/sec, so pretty sure NOT a network issue.
2. takes 20-30 seconds for this to show up after hitting enter for #1
3. password prompt immediately follows #2
4. takes 15 seconds to show up after enter for password.
5. takes additional 30 seconds for this to show up after #4.
6. shows up immediately after #5; rest of ssh session in putty is fine and fast.

This is in SLES 11.4 x86-64 if it matters.  For the past few years, steps 1..6 took less than 2 seconds it was entirely the time it took to type your login name and password.  Now it's taking close to 60 seconds on average to complete the ssh login process to get to the prompt.

Comment: Try changing hosts lookup in nsswitch.conf to just use files, in order to rule out any DNS hijinks ?  Plus, what is being used for passwd lookup, plain old files, or some AD in play here ?

Comment: immediate fix!  took out the 2 or so `dns` guys that were listed after `files`, was for `hosts:` and `networks:`.